# how to keep all Filters Visible in Magento

Tags: layered-navigation, filter

I want keep all filter visible on result page suppose if i select price 40 to 50 and it will display the product from price range 40-50 on that page i want display all price filter range as previous list page.in bellow code i was try for price attribute but when i selet one price range its not displying all price filter option on result page.

i have tried this code form this link http://inchoo.net/magento/layered-navigation-but-not-quite/

my website link:- [click here](http://www.ivybazaar.com/taste-of-india?p=2)

```
<?php $_filters = $this->getActiveFilters() ?>
<?php $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation(); ?>
<?php $_current_category=$obj->getCurrentCategory()->getUrlPath(); ?>
<?php $subs = $obj->getCurrentCategory()->getAllChildren(true); ?> 

<?php if(!empty($_filters)): ?>
<div class="state">
    <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Currently Shopping by:') ?></p>
    <dl>
    <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                    <?php $attributemodel=$_filter->filter->_data["attribute_model"]; ?>    
                    <?php $attroptions=$attributemodel->getSource()->getAllOptions();?>  
                    <?php $_categ= Mage::getModel('catalog/category');?>  

                <?php foreach($subs as $cat_id): ?>
                        <?php $_categ->load($cat_id)?>           
                        <?php $collection = $_categ->getProductCollection(); ?> 
                        <?php $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price')?>   
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                 <?php foreach($attroptions as $attr): ?>  
                        <?php $count=0; ?>
                        <?php if($attr["value"]!=""): ?>
                                <?php $val=$attr["value"] ?>
                                <?php $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'themes','gt'=>10)))?>  

                                <?php $proddata=$collection->getData() ?> 
                                <?php if($attr["label"]!= $this->stripTags($_filter->getLabel())): ?>  
                                    <?php foreach($proddata as $prod):?>
                                        <?php //if($prod["type_id"]=="configurable"): ?> 
                                          <?php if($prod["type_id"]=="simple"): ?>                                      
                                            <?php $split=split(",", $prod["price"]);?>
     <?php foreach($split as $color): ?>  
                                                <?php if($color==$attr["value"]): ?>
                                                    <?php $count++;?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>

                                        <?php endif;?>

                                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                                    <?php if($count>0):?>  
                                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('').$_current_category ?>?price=<?php echo $attr["value"]?>" ><?php echo  $attr["label"]; ?></a></li>  
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php else:?>
                                    <li class="current"> <?php echo $this->stripTags($_filter->getLabel()); ?></li>  
                                <?php endif;?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach;  ?>

<?php endforeach; ?> 
                </ol>

            </dd>
    </dl>
    <a class="all" style="float:right;" href="<?php echo $this->getClearUrl()?>">All</a>    
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: There are many tutorials available online to achieve this. Before posting a question, please do a quick search in google. Giving you a wonderful link along with this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88218/how-to-show-layered-navigation-filter-all-time