# How to show layered navigation filter all time

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, filter

I have seen lots of people who discussed about this issue, also given plenty of ideas, but i am still stuck at the issue. As per the answer at this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71533/how-to-not-remove-layered-navigation-options-which-are-removed-after-selecting), i have written the new function to get the active filters value at `view.php`

app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php,

```
public function getActiveFilters()
    {
        $filters = $this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters();
        foreach($filters as $filter){
            $active[] = $this->getChild($filter->getFilter()->getRequestVar().'_filter');
        }
        return $active;
    }
```

this function gives the value of the current filter `name`,`label`.

at view.phtml,

```
$_active = $this->getActiveFilters();

foreach ($_active as $active) {?>

   <select class="filter_box col-xs-12" onchange="filter(this.value)">
    <option value="#"><?php echo $this->__($active->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php echo $active->getHtml() ?>
    </select>
<?php }?>
```

In this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71533/how-to-not-remove-layered-navigation-options-which-are-removed-after-selecting), @B00MER mentioned extending the filter class will solve the issue also provided the code for the Category Filter. I have checked it at my magento site, but there is no changes. It is just displaying the filter without any option.

I don't know how to achieve it, also don't know the method which i am using ,is correct or not.

Can someone point me the right solution for this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show filters all time in layered navigation, I have rewritten the magento catalog core classes,
For Attribute Filters, 
rewrite class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute`,

replace the following line at `applyFilterToCollection` function

```
$tableAlias = $attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_idx';
```

by,

```
$tableAlias = $attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_idx_'.$value;
```

rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute`,

Comment Out the `$this->_items = array();` at the function `apply`,

```
public function apply(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, $filterBlock)
    {
        $filter = $request->getParam($this->_requestVar);
        if (is_array($filter)) {
            return $this;
        }
        $text = $this->_getOptionText($filter);
        if ($filter && strlen($text)) {
            $this->_getResource()->applyFilterToCollection($this, $filter);
            $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($this->_createItem($text, $filter));
            //$this->_items = array();
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item` to add the following method,

```
public function isSelected(){
        $selected = Mage::getSingleton('core/app')->getRequest()->getParam($this->getFilter()->getRequestVar());

        if($selected == $this->getValue()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

`isSelected()` used for getting attribute clear url at the `filter.phtml`

The above steps will help to show all attributes at all time.

Ref:https://dhimandey.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/show-all-attributes-after-filter-in-layered-navigation/

For Price Filter,

rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price`,
comment out the `else` condition at the `_getItemsData`

```
protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_RANGE_CALCULATION) == self::RANGE_CALCULATION_IMPROVED) {
            return $this->_getCalculatedItemsData();

        } /*elseif ($this->getInterval()) {
            //return array();
        }*/

        $range      = $this->getPriceRange();
        $dbRanges   = $this->getRangeItemCounts($range);
        $data       = array();

        if (!empty($dbRanges)) {
            $lastIndex = array_keys($dbRanges);
            $lastIndex = $lastIndex[count($lastIndex) - 1];

            foreach ($dbRanges as $index => $count) {
                $fromPrice = ($index == 1) ? '' : (($index - 1) * $range);
                $toPrice = ($index == $lastIndex) ? '' : ($index * $range);

                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => $this->_renderRangeLabel($fromPrice, $toPrice),
                    'value' => $fromPrice . '-' . $toPrice,
                    'count' => $count,
                );
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

This will helps to retain the price filter at all time. I hope this answer will help someone.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer because it does what it says on the box, however there is one shortcoming, when filter is applied and you click on another filter option its not responsive. In other words filter is displayed, but it does not reapply filter if used again. Any solution to that?

Comment: The numbers behind all filter options are "0" once a filter is selected for the attribute. Any fix for that?

Comment: how can i do the same in magento 2?